# Changing vertical spacing of text under an underbrace?

Tags: spacing, subscripts, underbrace

New to all this, still lots of learning.

I've been able to modify the vertical spacing between the underbrace and the equation, but when I try to put text underneath the brace it seems to be hugging it just a bit too tightly. Not sure what to do, help would be appreciated.

Will try and give an mwe, let me know if its not helpful lol:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*\mystrut[1]{\vrule width0pt height0pt depth#1\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    ^9P_3 = \underbrace{\mystrut{0.5ex} 9 \times 8 \times 7}_{\text{3 times}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this like you want? I defined a `\tvstrut` and a `\bvstrut`(for ‘top’ and ‘bottom’ struts), based on the recent package `spacingtricks`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{spacingtricks}
\newcommand*\tstrut[1]{\vstrut{#1}}
\newcommand*\bstrut[1]{\vstrut[#1]{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    ^{9\!}P_3 = \underbrace{\bstrut{0.5ex}9 \times 8 \times 7}_{\tstrut{1.5ex}\text{3 times}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fuar lit thanks thats perfect